# Does the US Executive Order 13884 (August 5, 2019) target the Property of the Government of Venezuela only or of all Venezuelans?

Tags: united-states, international, sanctions, venezuela

Does the [US Executive Order 13884 (August 5, 2019)](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2019/08/07/2019-17052/blocking-property-of-the-government-of-venezuela) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191007223157/https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2019/08/07/2019-17052/blocking-property-of-the-government-of-venezuela)) target the  Property of the Government of Venezuela or of all Venezuelans?

https://helpx.adobe.com/la/x-productkb/policy-pricing/executive-order-venezuela.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20191007223200/https://helpx.adobe.com/la/x-productkb/policy-pricing/executive-order-venezuela.html)) says:

> The U.S. Government issued Executive Order 13884, the practical effect of which  is to prohibit almost all  transactions and services between U.S. companies, entities, and individuals in Venezuela.

However https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2019/08/07/2019-17052/blocking-property-of-the-government-of-venezuela says:

> (d) the term “Government of Venezuela” includes the state and Government of Venezuela, any political subdivision, agency, or instrumentality thereof, including the Central Bank of Venezuela and Petroleos de Venezuela, S.A. (PdVSA), any person owned or controlled, directly or indirectly, by the foregoing, and any person who has acted or purported to act directly or indirectly for or on behalf of, any of the foregoing, including as a member of the Maduro regime. For the purposes of section 2 of this order, the term “Government of Venezuela” shall not include any United States citizen, any permanent resident alien of the United States, any alien lawfully admitted to the United States, or any alien holding a valid United States visa.

so it's unclear to me whether the US Executive Order 13884 (August 5, 2019) targets the Property of the Government of Venezuela only or of all Venezuelans.

Answer (score 3):

> so it's unclear to me whether the US Executive Order 13884 (August 5, 2019) targets the Property of the Government of Venezuela only or of all Venezuelans.

Neither.  By its literal text, it excludes any Venezuelan who is a citizen of the US, a green card holder, or lawfully present in the US, or who holds a valid US visa.  More pertinently to your question, perhaps, it also excludes any Venezuelan who has never been an agent of (or purported to be an agent of) Venezuela or any of its political subdivisions, agencies, or instrumentalities.